# Windows forms : color dialog solid color only

Tags: winforms, colordialog

After chekcing the options on the ColorDialog of Windows forms, I was wondering the difference between putting **SolidColorOnly** propertie to true or false (in other words what is a *Solid color* and what is not).

Comment: I did, but the only thing I could find was a lot of pages saying that it allows you to restrict the user to selecting only solid colors, which doesn't tell me a lot about what is a solid color and what is not :P

Comment: IMO this is a valuable quirk worth documenting (that isn't documented in many places) since not many people still run with 256 colors. I'd rewrite it to something like this if I had the rep: Title: "What does the `ColorDialog.SolidColorOnly` property do?", Body: "I tried setting this to `true` and `false` but I saw no difference on my (32 bit color) system (show a screenshot), and I don't see any non-solid colors."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know what solid color means, then the question could be "What solid color means?".

A solid color means that all pixels have the same color. For a single pixel it doesn't make much sense, but a larger area can be colored with some kind of raster consisting of pixels in more than one color. When such area is viewed from a distance, it almost looks like another color.

Edit: Picture of windows color select dialog in 256 colors

[image: Picture of windows color select dialog in 256 colors]

Comment: But how could someone select a non solid color inv a color dialog

Comment: See the pic above. Where it reads "Väri | Tasainen" yoy can clearly see the difference between a solid and non-solid colors, as well as  in the color palette in the top.

Comment: Is it really possible to select such a color in a Windows forms' ColorDialog ?

Comment: I think it i, but those colors aren't really useful anymore, when everyone has 32bit colors or better. 20 years ago it was ok.